# jQuery Datatable Error Loading Large Data 4Mb

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) v1.10.13 with serverSide implementation. The table has four columns. On last column I've a button to allow user to download CSV file. The content of CSV file is fetched during datatable Ajax call and manipulated in "dataSrc" callback.

Today I get the data of around 4MB for one of CSV file. Upon loading such content jQuery datatable throws error and "dataSrc" callback is not triggered.

Error show in JS alert:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

In chrome console it says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Though I debugged server side code and there is not exception or error reported.

Part of code snippet:

```
"ajax": {
"url": ajaxUrl,
"type": "POST",
"dataType": "JSON",
"dataSrc": function (json) {

    let localCreatedDate = null;
    debugger;
    for (let i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {                        
        localCreatedDate = json.data[i].CreatedDateString;
        json.data[i].CreatedDate = json.data[i].CreatedDateString;
        json.data[i].FromDate = json.data[i].FromDateString;
        json.data[i].ToDate = json.data[i].ToDateString;
        json.data[i].Status = '<div class="ellipses-general-550" title="' + json.data[i].Status + '">' + (json.data[i].Status || "") + '</div>';
        json.data[i].Action = `<input type="button" value="Download" Class="btn btn-primary" onclick='download("csvuploaded ${localCreatedDate}.csv", "${json.data[i].CSVContent}")' />`; 
    }
    return json.data;
}
```

Even I just fetch one row (if that row contains ~4MB CSV content) the error shows up. Datatable works perfectly fine without this culprit file.

Looking for some solutions or workarounds. Thanks.

Comment: Why dont use get the data from a click event instead of append the data to your button ?

Comment: Good question. But data is readily available in one request, so why make an extra request? Usually data is not large but for one such case it’s containing data in MBs. Is there any limitation at data tables level?

Comment: I dont think there is such limitation, I load up to 80K records to a datatable thats a lot of data maybe is something wrong  with the process you are doing, It will be nice to see more code and an example of your json array from the ajax call